# What costume am I missing?

Tags: steam, pc, batman-arkham-knight

I have the PC version of Arkham Knight, preordered from Steam with the season pass and this missing gap is killing me and my OCD.  I have already 200% the game, logged in with WBPlay, got 3 stars on all of the AR challenges, 100% the Harley Quinn DLC.  But there's a blemish on my completion, the game shows I have 103/104 showcase items.  The only things that are missing is this costume in the screenshot (9/14) and maybe 3 or so other achievements.

**What is the missing costume in this version of the game and how do I get it?**

As far as I know, I should have everything in this game at this point.  Getting all achievements typically doesn't unlock game items so I wouldn't expect that to be holding me back.

[image: Showcase]

For reference, here's the names of the costumes in the slots (from top-left across):

1. **Batsuit V7.43**
2. **Batsuit V8.03**
3. **Batsuit V8.04**
4. **New 52 Batman Skin**
5. **Batman Flashpoint Skin**
6. **Batman Beyond Skin**
7. **Dark Knight Returns Batman Skin**
8. **Anime Batman Skin**
9. *missing*
10. **Robin**
11. **New 52 Robin Skin**
12. **Catwoman**
13. **Nightwing**
14. **New 52 Nightwing Skin**

It appears to be a Batman costume.  And most listings I can find mix in console exclusive costumes so I can't be sure what belongs to what.  No other DLC items have been released for PC yet and of course, we don't have any of the PS4 exclusives so it can't be the Adam West costume.

Comment: Could it be bat girl? Tho, bat girl does require a separate dlc

Comment: Not likely. The DLC will be coming eventually so I'd expect it to be available when they release the next patch that fixes the game and adds the missing content.

Comment: Appears the DLC is not out yet, on PC. That would be my mistake

Comment: Can you confirm if any of these slots were "vacant" before you purchased their respective DLCs? If it does, in fact, count skins from other versions, you would be missing the skin from the Serious Edition, which was exclusive to Amazon. While I can only find a PlayStation listing, there is a specific exclusive for people playing on PlayStation, suggesting it was available for other platforms. I find it hard to believe you would be expected to purchase two special editions, tho

Comment: There is speculation this skin is going to be released, again, as it was with others.

Comment: I had whatever DLC came with a preordered Steam release with the season pass and the WBPlay skin. I had this since I installed. All slots that were vacant were eventually unlocked, except for this one which I don't know is unlockable or to-be-released DLC.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood my question. **Were there vacant slots for the DLC/Bonus skins, before you purchased the related DLC/Bonus**. Given you cant buy the game *bundled* with the season pass, this would at least apply to the season pass bonus skins. It is important to see whether batman still expects you to unlock skins associated with elements you have no access to, without paying. Season Pass is inclusive, in that while not inherently DLC, you pay for it in order to obtain DLCs.

Comment: That's possible. I just figured that given we haven't had a PC patch since the initial batch of fixes, I wouldn't think that hints of future DLC content wouldn't be patched in until closer to release. As a PC player playing a multi-platform game, I've grown accustomed to delays so I figured the new stuff wouldn't have come until mid-/late-August anyway (whether there was a problem with the game or not). Even before the new DLCs have been released, it seemed that console owners were able to unlock everything. I was expecting the same for us.

Comment: The costume I talk about was released with a special edition, much like the "Limited Edition" came with an exclusive costume already on your list. As I said, I am doubtful you would be expected to have BOTH "exlusive edition costumes", but would understand them leaving it in if they expected to add it with DLC. Being added with a new DLC **is just me speculating**. It is already possible for you to have the costume, on PC.

Comment: I think It is Batman zur en arh

Comment: Does WBPlay on the PC have the same problem unlocking the Zur-En-Arrh skin as PlayStation (and I assume Xbox) does? My guess is that the missing skin is Zur-En-Arrh.

Comment: @jlucktay: I haven't logged in to the game lately as there's nothing to do (I already 200% the game). But IIRC, one of the costumes was unlocked when registered (don't remember which exactly) and not much else.

Comment: @jlucktay: It turns out you were right. After looking at the WBPlay menu, it lists exactly what the reward is and what we need to do to unlock it.

Comment: @DanielV: yeah, it was.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out there are two costumes associated with signing up with WBPlay, one for getting an account and one for signing up to the WB Games forums.

The former grants the Anime Batman Skin.  The latter grants the Zur En Arrh Batman Skin.

I only linked my account but didn't sign in to the forums.  Doing so unlocks the reward.

[image: Zur En Arrh]